# Is there any way to automatically scale matching parentheses by default?

Tags: parentheses

I tend to use `\left(` and `\right)` (and its cousins) all over the place. Is there a way to make this automatic scaling the default behavior in math mode? On the very rare occasions that I don't want automatic scaling I'd then like to write `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same question. Sad to see that the best option seems to be defining new commands such as `\paren{}`.

Comment: The best option is *not* using indiscriminately `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Well, that's why you'd still have `\(` and `\)` to fall back on. But honestly, I could see myself writing pages and pages never needing those once. How could you possibly get into trouble?

Comment: I write pages and pages of math never needing a single `\left`-`\right` pair.

Comment: I can already see a difference between `(x^2)` and `\left(x^2\right)`. And it doesn't really hurt to scale the parentheses.

Comment: So you'd choose the top line in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFo8T.png)? Even not considering the wrong spacing, which is fixable, I find it is unacceptable.

Comment: Hm, you have a point there.